# Which classes must implement the Serializable interface?

Tags: java, serializable

I want to send an object via socket, so I have to implement Serializable. But my class is a compound class, like this simple code:

```
class B{
    private int a;
    public B(int aa){a=aa;}
}

class A {
    private B b;
    public A(B b1){ b=b1;}
}
```

I want to send an object of class A, with all it's contents such as the B object inside. Which classes should implement Serializable? just A, or both A and B?

---

Addition: How about vectors? Think that I have a Vector of B in A like this:

```
class A {
    private Vector bvector;
}
```

Comment: Vector is serializable.  Of course, the things inside it must be serializable as well.  If the things inside are instances of B then you must make B serializable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** serialize instances of A ,even if B is not declared as `Serializable`. The requirements for this is that

1. Class B must make available a default constructor ( and)
2. Class A must provide implementations of following methods :

   `private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois)`

   `private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos)`

It is definitely easier to serialize instances of A if class B is declared as
`Serializable` Vs when it is not. The default serialization could be made to work if it does.

Having a `Vector` of B makes no difference in the above situation ( it just adds another layer of structure ).

Comment: B doesn't need a default constructor, it just needs *any* constructor that is accessible to A.

Answer (score 3):

Both. `A` can't be serializable as long as it has a non-static member of type `B` and 1) variable `b` is not marked `transient` or 2) class `B` does not implement Serializable.

Comment: would you please answer the part i added to question?

Comment: @saeed `Vector` implements `Serializable`

Comment: @Matten- so should B implement Serializable?

Comment: @saeed yes, otherwise you'll get the Serialization exception when you attemp to send an object of type `A`

Answer (score 2):

If neither class is an inner class you can do it either way.  Simpler in many cases to serialize both independently.  But it's generally faster and more version-independent to serialize A and, instead of B, include the info needed to recreate B in A's serialization.

If one or both are inner classes then it gets messier/slower to serialize them, and better to include their recreation info in the outer class.

Of course, when objects of a class are referenced from multiple other objects, you usually have no choice but to serialize them separately.

Comment: would you please answer the part i added to question?

Answer (score 1):

If you won't make B serializable you will get Serialization exception.

Comment: would you please answer the part i added to question?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a wrapping class serialise Vector provided it is a field of another Serializable class, or sub class Vector to change its serializaton. This class can lock the Vector for Serialization and serialise A and B classes.  If you use this approach, you don't need to add a Serializable marker interface.

Comment: Peter Vector.writeObject() is synchronized, so it is thread safe. Didn't we have this discussion before?

Comment: We had a similar one re List vs Vector, Map vs Hashtable and whether one is a legacy class. I have removed to comment about Vector.writeObject being thread safe.