# How to send object over java socket (java networking) and read it

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, classnotfoundexception, outputstream

I want to make chat application using java networking. So far I have made server and client class in two different projects and each of them have the same Message class:

```
package client;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Message implements Serializable {

public static final long serialVersionUID = 1l;

private String text;
private int receiversID;
private int senderID;

public Message(String text, int receiversID, int senderID){
    this.text = text;
    this.receiversID = receiversID;
    this.senderID = senderID;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public int getReceiversID() {
    return receiversID;
}

public int getSenderID() {
    return senderID;
}
```

Than I send a message inside client class like this:

```
            do {
            System.out.print("Enter message to be sent: ");
            text = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter receivers ID: ");
            receiverID = scanner.nextInt();

            outputStream.writeObject(new Message(text, receiverID, ID)); // sending message
            outputStream.flush();

            if (!text.equals("exit")) {
                try {
                    Message message = (Message) inputStream.readObject();
                    System.out.print(message.getText() + "\n");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        } while (!text.equals("exit"));
```

The error occurs when I want to get that message in my server project:

```
        Message message = (Message) inputStream.readObject();
```

And I get this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: client.Message
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:683)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1863)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1746)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2037)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1568)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:428)
at network.ClientSockets.run(ClientSockets.java:57)
```

I know that server project can not recognize Message class from client despite they are the same classes, but I really don't know how to fix this.

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: The error says `at network.Client.run(Client.java:55)`.  Is the error on the server or the client?

Comment: its just a name, its not client class from another project, that class contains socket of client in server project

Comment: can you post line number 55 of Client (or rather check yourself more line 55 of Client)

Comment: Message message = (Message) inputStream.readObject();

Comment: hmm also check the package name of Message class at both Server and Client end

Comment: I have made client class too inside server project which contains sockets from clients, and that I put clients inside an array

Comment: you can try debugging : inputStream.readObject().getClass() It will let you know the actual class

Comment: To clarify, you have two `Message.java`'s, one in the client project and one in the server project?  Do they both have the same package name?  The error says that the server is looking for `client.Message`.

Comment: Nope, they don't have the same package name

Comment: Try giving them the same package name.

Comment: there you go!! you have two ends. End1 sends X.A to End2 and End2 has Y.A so tries to decode the recieved data and fails to recognize the data as it does not have X.A.

Comment: That is true, but still what shoud I do?

Comment: also this link may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/7050688/504133 I am not sure as I do not have PC to verify it now but may be you will have to implement Serializable interface and have same Serial version id at both client and server end for Message class

Comment: @nits.kk They've already done that.

Comment: Ideally the client and server should share the same source file.  Other than that, just try changing the package names to make them the same (`package client;` -> `package shared;` for example).

Comment: what shall i do ? My suggestion .. Same class name, keep it in same named package, implement Serializable interface and have same serial verdion id. I.e. have similar copies of Message class at both end Server as well as Client side. Do not make Message as inner class. *Keep it in same named package as a separate outer public class in its own java file*

Comment: It works!!! They all just have to have the same package names thanks you all !!!